# Image is not converted from Uri to Bitmap image in UWP

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp, image-conversion

I have referred the below thread for combing multiple images as single image in uwp.
[Merging multiple Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655074/merging-multiple-images)

But the image is not properly converted from Uri to bitmap images for the tiles downloaded from below link

https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png

```
  public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MergeImages();
        }

        async void MergeImages()
        {
            byte[] Canvas = new byte[512 * 512 * 4];

                Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(
                    new Uri("https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/0/0.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).OpenReadAsync();
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                byte[] tileImage = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
                Canvas = PutOnCanvas(Canvas, tileImage, 0,
                    0, 256, 256, 512);

            InMemoryRandomAccessStream memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, memStream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
               512, // pixel width
               512, // pixel height
                96, // horizontal DPI
                96, // vertical DPI
                Canvas);

            try
            {
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(memStream);
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
            catch { }
            memStream.Dispose();
        }

        byte[] PutOnCanvas(byte[] Canvas, byte[] Image, uint x, uint y, uint imageheight, uint imagewidth, uint CanvasWidth)
        {
            for (uint row = y; row < y + imageheight; row++)
                for (uint col = x; col < x + imagewidth; col++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        Canvas[(row * CanvasWidth + col) * 4 + i] = Image[((row - y) * imagewidth + (col - x)) * 4 + i];

            return Canvas;
        }
```

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/BitmapConversio1484632127)

[Actual Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxmAu.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5crf.png)

Comment: Why are you doing this at all, instead of putting multiple Image elements in a Grid?

Comment: In my case I want to add and remove images based on the pinching level(zoom level). If I directly use image control, I am getting flickering effect while adding and removing the images. That's why I want to combine multiple images as single one

Comment: Put multiple Grids on top of each other. And did you take a look at [this](https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control)? It smoothly blends zoom level layers.

Comment: Could not run the sample in that link

Comment: But you wouldn't tell why? What exactly didn't work with it?

Comment: I could run only the WPF sample. I am getting nuget restoring error for Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. Also, I have debugged WPF application. I could not understand why the TileGrid has been refreshed every time

Comment: "refreshed every time" - not sure what you mean with that. It is refreshed whenever necessary.

Comment: All the images are added child for MapTileLayer and TileGrid is not used anywhere so far, I have debugged and I dint understand how the flickering effect has been overcome everytime when clearing the children of MapTileLayer

Comment: Could u explain, how the flickering effect has been avoided when moving from one zoom level to another level?

Comment: That's done by animating the Opacity property of the Image elements that show the map tiles.

Comment: For the NuGet restore error, you could just open Package Manager for both the MapControl.UWP and UniversalApp projects, and update Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to the latest version.

Comment: @clemens if possible, could you provide any simple sample for animating the grid children with opacity , when dynamically removing or adding child in to it?

Answer (score 0):

I found your previous two threads:

[How to avoid the flickering effect when dynamically changes the image source in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980603/how-to-avoid-the-flickering-effect-when-dynamically-changes-the-image-source-in)

[How to combine multiple image as single image in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987124/how-to-combine-multiple-image-as-single-image-in-uwp)

They all aimed to avoid the flickering effect. As I comment in your second thread, the flickering effect is caused by you change the images's source in a short time, if you want to avoid it, you can use the animation to change the images with a progress. Here is a example to use the `DoubleAnimation` Storyboard to animate `Opacity` property of the Images stackpanel base on your first thread [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ImagesCacheAsync997382703.zip):

MainPage.xaml: I create two storyboard to make the images stackpanel disappear or display and give the `disappearStoryboard` a `disappearStoryboard_Completed` event handler.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="disappearStoryboard" Completed="disappearStoryboard_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="RootStackPanel"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Name="displayStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="RootStackPanel"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="RootStackPanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="image1" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom200.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image2" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom201.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image3" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom202.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image4" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom203.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="image5" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom210.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image6" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom211.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image7" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom212.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image8" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom213.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="image9"  Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom220.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image10" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom221.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image11" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom222.png"/>
            <Image x:Name="image12" Height="200" Width="200" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/custom223.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="ReplaceCustom" x:Name="replaceCustom" Click="replaceCustom_Click" Margin="5"/>

        <Button Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Replace OSM" x:Name="replaceOSM" Click="replace_Click" Margin="5"/>

        <Button Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Replace Tile" x:Name="replaceTile" Click="replaceTile_Click" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs: I change the Images' resource in the `disappearStoryboard` 's `disappearStoryboard_Completed` event handler.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool replaceButtonClicked, replaceCustomButtonClicked, replaceTileButtonClicked;

    private void replace_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        replaceButtonClicked = true;
        disappearStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void replaceCustom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        replaceCustomButtonClicked = true;
        disappearStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void replaceTile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        replaceTileButtonClicked = true;
        disappearStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void disappearStoryboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (replaceButtonClicked)
        {
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM200.png",
         UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM201.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM202.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM203.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image5.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM210.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image6.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM211.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image7.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM212.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image8.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM213.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image9.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM220.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image10.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM221.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image11.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM222.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image12.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM223.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            replaceButtonClicked = false;
        }
        if (replaceCustomButtonClicked)
        {
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom200.png",
         UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom201.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom202.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom203.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image5.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom210.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image6.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom211.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image7.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom212.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image8.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom213.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image9.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom220.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image10.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom221.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image11.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom222.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image12.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/custom223.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            replaceCustomButtonClicked = false;
        }
        if (replaceTileButtonClicked)
        {
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM300.png",
         UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM301.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM302.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM303.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image5.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM304.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image6.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM305.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image7.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM306.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image8.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM301.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image9.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM302.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image10.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM303.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image11.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM310.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            image12.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/OSM311.png",
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            replaceTileButtonClicked = false;
        }
        displayStoryboard.Begin();
    }

}
```